# How to sing with mix voice without raising my larynx and still being comfortable

Tags: technique, voice, practice, self-learning

Range:E2-E4 then F4-G4 is my break. I can sing an F4 in what I think is my mix sorta comfortably but slightly higher I tense up and my larynx rises. The only way I can sing the G-B range is by yelling.

I have tried to sing through the bridge with low larynx and pharyngeal resonance but all that gets me is an F4 with some volume but no extra range. So how can I sing with mix voice without raising my larynx and still being comfortable.

I'm kinda desperate here. I mean I can sing the bridge an octave higher WITH EASE but what I want to sing with ease I can't. Any info will be very much appreciated

Comment: "the bridge" do you mean the bridge of a song?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - probably not. OP must mean bridge from chest to head voice.